# Console2 cygwin all green

Tags: cygwin, console2

I just set up Console2 and cygwin. All defaul settings.

Then in Console2 settings I configured new tab to use cygwin (set `Shell` to `C:\programs\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`).

Now when I open cygwin console font is green. Part of prompt have different color, but when I type characters are green.

I used to use this configuration before and never have such problem.

**PS:** When I launch Cygwin.bat from explorer situation is same. But when I do it from FAR Manager all colors are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that I runned `bash.exe` from `explorer`, opened `Defaults` menu and changed `Screen Text` property in `Colors` tab.

Thanks ti @Maximus for idea

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have this colors configured in Windows console defaults. Run `cmd` from Win-R and check result.